# how to add to a php array without reinitializing it

Tags: php, arrays

I want to add values to an array by posting them from a form in another php file. I do not want to use the include or require methods as there replicate the entire file I intent to include. When using the following code:

```
if (isset($array)) {
    echo "Array has been initialzied ...";
    //do nothing
}   
else{ // initialize array
    echo "Initializing array ...";
    $array = array();
}
```

Whenever I reload the page my array still gets reinitialized.

Please suggest how I should initialize my array so that it doesn't reinitialize every time I reload the page.

Comment: use [sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php).

Comment: Initialize array at the top of the code. And then pass the `$_POST` value to the array. And below it. For the if condition. Check if array is empty or not.